# c_str() == NULL not working

Tags: c++

I was going through legacy code to fix a problem and found out that checking c_str in the following manner does not work. However if I change the comparison to string.empty() it works. So my problem is solved, but I am not sure why the c_str comparison does not work.Any idea why?
Thanks!
I am using - gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46).

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main()
{
   string a="";
   if (a.c_str() == NULL)
   {
     cout <<"char says empty"<<endl;
   }
   if (a.empty())
  {
    cout << "string says empty"<<endl;
  } 
 }
```

The output is-
        string says I am empty

Comment: really? I mean a is empty is not NULL, NULL != "".

Comment: I think the standard actually *requires* `std::string::c_str()` to return a non-null pointer.

Comment: An empty string and no string at all are two distinct things.

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place? C or C++. Pick one and go with it. But don't try to write C in C++.

Comment: @John I can't do much about the code, as it's legacy code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is not null in this case.  The string object has an internal pointer, which is not `null`, and that pointer is what c_str returns.

To verify this, try

```
printf("%zu\n", a.c_str());
```

and you will get a real address.

Answer (score 5):

A null terminated string is never `NULL`, it always points to valid memory with a null terminator. The empty string is just a single `\0`. Since `c_str()` is contracted to return a null terminated string it can never return `NULL`. The correct way to test for an empty string is indeed `empty()`.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, with an empty string, `.c_str()` is probably returning a non-NULL string to some memory, with the first byte set to '\0'. IOW, you're getting a zero-length string, not a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

std::string is not required to use NULL for storing empty strings.

On the other hand, c_str() is required to return a *pointer to a null-terminated sequence of characters*. The minimum memory size for this sequence is 1 (the required for the '\0'). So it cannot be NULL.

The right way to check if a std::string is empty is to call the empty() method.

You may also notice that on the following code:

```
char a[] = "";
```

The variable **a** is not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is not a null string, it is an empty string.  In memory, it would contain a single character, `\0`.  A null string, on the other hand, contains no characters: it doesn't even point to anything.  Two completely different types of "empty", only one of which you test for.